# Finding entries from list in strings

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
names = ['Jim','Billy','Diana']
```

I have a file where each line is:

```
Jim and Billy went to see Diana.
Diana was at the Mall.
Billy and Diana are siblings.
```

I need the output file to look like:

```
'Jim', 'Billy', 'Diana'
'Diana'
'Billy', 'Diana'
```

Here's what I've got that doesn't work:

```
f = open("storyfile.txt","r")
names = ['Jim','Billy','Diana']
for line in f:
  if names in line:
    print(names)
f.close()
```

This returns:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Not sure what I could be doing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `if names in line` you're instructing your program to see if the entire array is inside a single string... a comparison it can't make, and so it complains.

You'll want to split each line from the file into separate words that you can search for too:

```
for line in f:
  for word in line.split(" "):
    if word in names:
      print(word + ","),
  print("\n")
```

Output:

```
Jim, Billy,
Diana,
Billy, Diana,
```

That'll leave you with an extra comma at the end of each printed line but I'm sure you can figure out some logic to get rid of that...

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("storyfile.txt","r")
names = ['Jim','Billy','Diana']
for line in f:
    print([name for name in names if name in line])
f.close()
```